# Unable to get data attribute from button element via Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm not able to get the data attribute from a button element.

```
<button
class="btn btn-solid navigate"
value="2"
data-productId={{$product->id}}
id="size-click"
>
Next
</button>
```

Then I attempt to get it like so:

```
  $("#size-click").click(() => {
    let width = $("#prod-width").val();
    let height = $("#prod-height").val();
    var prodId = $(this).data("productId");

    console.log('this is prodId');
    console.log(prodId);

    const data = {
      prodId: prodId,
      step: 'Size',
      width: width,
      height: height,
    }

    postDataEstimate(data);

  })
```

I'm also trying this:

```
var prodId = $(this).attr('data-productId');
```

Can you let me know what I'm missing?

Comment: Where are you trying to get ``prodId``?

Comment: In a separate js file.  @MajedBadawi

Comment: @MajedBadawi I just updated the code to show where I'm trying to get it.

Comment: your are missing quotes `data-productId={{$product->id}}` Your markup breaks after that

Comment: This doesn't work either: data-productId="{{$product->id}}". @ikiK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an `arrow-function`, `this` does not refer to the `button`:

```js
$("#size-click").click(function() {
  var prodId = $(this).attr("data-productId");
  console.log('this is prodId');
  console.log(prodId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button
  class="btn btn-solid navigate"
  value="2"
  data-productId="1"
  id="size-click"
>Next</button>
```

If you still want to use it, you can use the `event` passed to the function:

```js
$("#size-click").click(e => {
  var prodId = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-productId");
  console.log('this is prodId');
  console.log(prodId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button
  class="btn btn-solid navigate"
  value="2"
  data-productId="1"
  id="size-click"
>Next</button>
```